# How can I get all <tr>-s from a <tbody> and convert it to String?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, html-table

I have a HTML Table:

```
<table id="persons" border="1">
    <thead id="theadID">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>sex</th>
            <th>Message</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbodyID">
        <tr>
            <td>Viktor</td>
            <td>Male</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Melissa</td>
            <td>Female</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Joe</td>
            <td>Male</td>
            <td>etc</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="getTbodyString();" value="get it"/>
```

I want some jquery/javascript, which can get the inside of the tbody by String. Like:

```
function getTbodyString() {
    var tbodyString = $(.......).text(); //or val()?
    alert("the body - "+tbodyString);
}
```

The result in the alert window should be this:

```
the body - <tr><td>Viktor</td><td>Male</td><td>etc</td></tr><tr><td>Melissa</td><td>Female</td><td>etc</td></tr><tr><td>Joe</td><td>Male</td><td>etc</td></tr>
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: `$('#tbodyID').html();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of text(). The function text will not return you tags but returns plain text within tags.

```
var tbodyString = $('#tbodyID').html();
```

I would use native javascript function here that would be faster then jquery.

```
var tbodyString = document.getElementById('tbodyID').innerHTML;
```

Comment: and how can I get the <tr>-s without their last <td>??

Comment: you can use ->  .not(':last') jquery selector

Comment: could you give me some example?

Answer (score 1):

Just Replace your function code as below :

```
function getTbodyString() {
    var tbodyString = $('#tbodyID').html(); 
    alert("the body - "+tbodyString);
}
```